# Is this normal in CSS?

Tags: html, css

The background of the BODY tag extends to fit the sidebar, but the background of the `#wrap` element doesn't. Why?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="side"> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> test <br> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background: #333;    
}

#wrap{
    position: relative;
    background: #cc4;       
}

#side{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

[**#Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hud5T/)

Comment: Its because you are using the absolute position that you applied to it. The absolute make it float above. If you edit the code and apply this: `#side{ background-color: #cc4;}` or just simply remove the `position`. The issue will be fixed!

Comment: So this is normal in CSS!

Comment: but why does BODY extend then? Shouldn't it behave like the DIV?

Comment: No, the body tag has to be there. As the body tag has some CSS it will always apply. The second div with id wrap is having some style. But which is placed underneath, the one that is placed above is having the position element. Which override the other div. Either try removing the position property or try to using the wrap properties for the third div (#side)

Comment: Also the body is not like a div, but its a container! That is compulsary to be there. Its not a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its due to your `#side` being absolute.

It's like floating where it thinks the content is empty.

If you remove position absolute off from `#side`, then it works.

It just thinks the box is empty and so there is nothing to put a background on.

Answer (score 2):

The `#wrap` element has no content, hence no height, so the background color is not visible.

If you specified a height value, you would see it, for example:

```
#wrap{
    position: relative;
    background: #cc4;     
    height: 400px;
}
```

The `#side` element is absolutely positioned so it does not contribute to the height of the parent container (using absolute position takes the element out of the normal content flow).

You are seeing the expected behavior for the CSS rules that you defined.

Since the `body` tag is the root level container, it encloses everything, including all floated and absolutely positioned descendant elements, hence, the background color (or image) covers everything.

Answer (score 1):

It's the absolute positioning over the Side element I believe.